# Why is this structure described using the word "jacket"?

Tags: word-meaning

From an [answer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/11412/349) on Engineering SE:

> It's very likely they are **jacket foundations** for offshore wind turbines. The excellent 4C Offshore has a database of such vessels used on offshore wind farms. It also has a list of all offshore windfarms under construction by country, and tells you which vessels are working on it, so given that you know where the photo was taken, you may able to work out which farm it's supplying.

But why is such a foundation a "jacket" foundation? I looked up the meanings of "[jacket](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jacket)" in Merriam-Webster, and none seems to fit. I know that usually the word is used in industrial texts to describe some kind of cover. Example: "[jacketed vessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacketed_vessel)." But in this case, it's just a frame supporting the wind turbine.

A picture containing a "jacket":

[image]

Comment: I believe the jacket is a cladding, a form of corrosion protection in highly corrosive saltwater environments.

Comment: http://www.jfe-eng.co.jp/en/products/infrastructure/coast/co04.html

Comment: http://www.jfe-eng.co.jp/en/products/infrastructure/coast/co02.html

Comment: @TRomano - The standard protection in such environment is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_anode), IMHO

Comment: Anodic protection is one type of protection. Jackets have a girder inside, and the jacket can be clad with stainless steel. http://www.jfe-eng.co.jp/en/products/link/kanren04.html

Comment: @TRomano - but that does not explain the choice of the word "jacket". Maybe it was just called that without any particular reason.

Comment: The jacket is a hollow pipe, often (not always) with a pile inside. The jacket protects that pile while helping to distribute the load.

Comment: This book refers to the entire three-dimensional structure (not just the leg) as the "jacket". https://books.google.com/books?id=2lm5zXTivm4C&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=steel+construction+jackets+seawater&source=bl&ots=TpAkuX-W09&sig=3XoKZ2L1I-2QvLZHxe6UsrFx7qw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpsq3Zh4LPAhWDNj4KHcggAAMQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=jacket&f=false

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason the outer casing of a bullet is called a "jacket". With this type of foundation, the platform is supported by an outer casing stabilized with a lattice rather than a post.

Answer (score 0):

The topsides weight is generally transferred to the foundation system via a "leg-through-pile". The "jacket" structure is protecting the pile from the environmental loads and later transfer that loads to the pile. 
I guess that is how the term "jacket" coming from. :)